# backbone: initialize model subclasses with additional attributes

Tags: javascript, inheritance, backbone.js, model

I'm new to backbone, so please bear with me. I would like to create a collection in which the models all have a handful of critical attributes which they share as well as a number of other attributes which they do not share. I thought the best way to do this would be to extend a superclass model (containing defaults for all of the shared attributes) such that when I instantiate a new subclass model, those attributes are initialized and additional attributes specific to the subclass are also added to the model. I don't know how to accomplish this, but here is the direction I've been working in:

```
app.Fruit = Backbone.Model.extend(
{

    defaults: {
        name: "none",
        classification: "none",
        color: "none"
    },

    initialize: function()
    {
        console.log("Fruit Initialized");
    }

});

app.Apple = app.Fruit.extend(
{

    url: "/php/Apple.php",

    initialize: function()
    {
        console.log("Apple initialized");
        // somehow fetch additional information from server
        // and add sublcass-specific attributes to model
        // (for example, in the case of an apple, an attribute called cultivar)
    }

});


var FruitCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend(
{

    model: function(attributes, options)
    {

        switch(attributes.name)
        {

        case "Apple":
            return new app.Apple(attributes, options);
            break;

            default:
            return new app.Fruit(attributes, options);
            break;

        }

    }

    // ...

});

app.fruitCollectionCurrent = new FruitCollection([
    {name: "Apple"},
    {name: "Orange"}
]);

// logs: Fruit Initialized
```

Any suggestions on how to properly initialize a subclass with additional attributes would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT: THE SOLUTION**

I thought I would post the code that ended up working for me... Arrived at it thanks to @Mohsen:

```
app.Fruit = Backbone.Model.extend(
{

    defaults: {
        name: "none",
        classification: "none",
        color: "none"
    },

    initialize: function()
    {
        console.log("Fruit Initialized");
    }

});

app.Apple = app.Fruit.extend(
{

    url: "/php/Apple.php",

    initialize: function()
    {
        console.log("Apple initialized");
        return this.fetch();
    }

});
```

I didn't even really need the asynchronous call in the subclass because I wasn't fetching any additional data for Fruit (Fruit's attributes were just set in the constructor), only for Apple. What I was really looking for was the call to this.fetch() with the specified URL. Sorry if the question made things seem more complex...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone is not easy to work with when it comes to hierarchy. I solve this problem by calling parent model/collection initializer inside of my child model/collection initializer.

```
Fruit = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: "/fruits:id",
    initialize: function initialize () {
        this.set('isWashed', false);
        return this.fetch();
    }
});

Apple = Fruit.extend({
    url: "/fruits/apples:id"
    initialize: function initialize () {
            var that = this;
        Fruit.prototype.initialize.call(this, arguments).then(function(){
            that.fetch();
        })
        this.set("hasSeed", true);
    }
});
```

Now your `Apple` model does have all properties of a `Fruit`.

Key line is `Fruit.prototype.initialize.call(this, arguments);`. You call initialize method of `Fruit` for `Apple`.

You can also use `this.__super__` to access parent model:

`this.__super__.prototype.initialize.call(this, arguments);`

Comment: A couple of things: In the code above, the initialize method in Apple never gets called for some reason. But barring that issue, how would I also fetch the subclass-specific attributes?

Comment: @adekom I updated my answer. You have to asynchronously fetch parent and child models.

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right track. I posted my actual implementation above.

Comment: A related issue that has popped up as a result of this solution: a call to this.model.toJSON() within Apple only returns those attributes set in Fruit. How would I overcome this?

Comment: You can override `toJSON`. make it call fetch, return a promise and resolve the promise with `Backbone.Model.toJSON` on fetch success. Your `toJSON` won't return a naked object anymore which is non-standard. But Backbone is not made for asynchrones programming.